# Touch / Tap on mobile seems to reset accordion tabs in jQuery

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile

I have an issue and cannot work it out, rather important as I'm sure is affecting sales / conversion rates from mobile devices as the issue in question is frustrating even for myself.

If you go to: https://rebrand.ly/ee00 from a mobile device (I get using my iPhone)

And scroll down, the first tab is open by default... go down a little more and click on the other tabs... most of the time it will open then it seems to reset and open up the first default one? You will see what I mean when you try.

I just changed the mobile events from touchstart to touchend to see if that helped but did not and at a loss to why it's doing it? Does anyone have any thoughts or ideas?

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var originalTabs = $('.originalTabs').html();

function clearTabs() {
  $('.originalTabs').html(originalTabs);
}

//clearTabs();
//desktopTabs(); 

function desktopTabs() {
  clearTabs();

  // cretate tabs for desktop
  var headers = $("#tab_description h6");

  $('#tab_description h6').each(function(i) {
    $(this).nextUntil("h6").andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="tab" id="tab-' + i + '"/>');
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
    $('.tabs').append('<li class=""><a href="#tab-' + i + '">' + headers[i].innerHTML + '</a></li>');
  }

  $('ul.tabs').each(function() {
    var active, content, links = $(this).find('a');
    var listitem = $(this).find('li');
    active = listitem.first().addClass('active');
    content = $(active.attr('href'));
    $('.tab').hide();
    $(this).find('a').click(function(e) {
      $('.tab').hide();
      $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('active');
      content.hide();
      active = $(this);
      content = $($(this).attr('href'));
      active.parent().addClass('active');
      content.show();
      return false;
    });
  });

  headers.remove(); // remove headers from description  
  $('#tab-0').show(); // show the first tab
}

function mobileTabs() {
  clearTabs();

  //alert("loaded mobile");

  var headers = $("#tab_description h6");

  $(headers).each(function(i) {
    $(this).append('<a href="#accordion_' + (i + 1) + '" id="accordion_' + (i + 1) + '"></a>');
    //$(this).nextUntil("h6").andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="aTab" id="tab-'+i+'"/>');
    $(this).on('click', function() {
      tabClick($(this));
    });
  });

  $('#tab_description h6').first().trigger('click').addClass("active");
  $('#tab_description h6').first().nextUntil("h6").show();
}

var tabClick = function(x) {

  //alert("clicked");
  var accordionContent = $('#tab_description p, #tab_description ul, #tab_description table, #tab_description div');

  $('#tab_description h6').removeClass("active");
  if (!$(x).hasClass("active")) {
    $(x).addClass("active");
  }

  // Check if current accordion item is open
  var isOpen = $(x).next().is(":visible");

  // Hide all accordion items
  accordionContent.hide();

  //console.log(x);
  // Open accordion item if previously closed
  if (!isOpen) {
    $(x).nextUntil('h6').show();
    $(x).nextUntil(accordionContent).show();
  }

  // Disabled to stop on mobile auto scrolling down to product description when clicking through...
  //$('html, body').animate({
  //    scrollTop: $(x).offset().top - 15
  //}, 2000);

  //return false;
}

//bind to resize
$(window).resize(function() {
  if (isMobileLandscapeOnly.matches || isTabletLandscapeOnly.matches) {
    desktopTabs();
    $('#tab_description h6').on("click, touchend", tabClick);

  } else if (isMobilePortraitOnly.matches || isTabletPortraitOnly.matches) {
    mobileTabs();
    $('#tab_description h6').on("click, touchend", tabClick);

  } else if (isDesktop) {
    desktopTabs();
  }
});

//check for the orientation event and bind accordingly
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
  if (isMobileLandscapeOnly.matches || isTabletLandscapeOnly.matches) {
    desktopTabs();
    $('#tab_description h6').on("click, touchend", tabClick);

  } else if (isMobilePortraitOnly.matches || isTabletPortraitOnly.matches) {
    mobileTabs();
    $('#tab_description h6').on("click, touchend", tabClick);

  } else if (isDesktop) {
    desktopTabs();
  }
}, false);

if (isMobileLandscapeOnly.matches || isTabletLandscapeOnly.matches) {
  //alert("Mobile / Tablet (Portrait)");
  desktopTabs();
  $('#tab_description h6').on("click, touchend", tabClick);

  //console.log(originalTabs);
} else if (isMobilePortraitOnly.matches || isTabletPortraitOnly.matches) {
  //alert("Mobile / Tablet (Portrait)");
  mobileTabs();
  $('#tab_description h6').on("click, touchend", tabClick);

} else if (isDesktop) {
  //alert("Desktop");
  desktopTabs();
}

});
```

### Update

I just had another play on my phone: if I change the tab and swipe down the content it is fine, change again and swipe down it is fine. It seems if I start to swipe back up it then resets, closes and opens the first one; it's really strange.

Comment: Its so weird when only swiping up... this is a new one to me for sure!

Comment: I have worked out the cause of the issue and it is the resize event... i guess would be good checking resize for width only?

Comment: Still had some issues but not as bad, would be great if someone would lend a hand for a proper fixture for this :) thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi James,it may sounds ugly, but really, if you are under time pressure, you should stop handle resize and orientationchange by yourself in code, because this will be a never-ending story. Devices have inconsistent behavior, so write less code as possible for that, use only CSS. Just my two cents to try to help you.

Comment: The shortlink provided leads to [this 404ing page](https://www.ambientlounge.eu/collections/butterfly-sofa-1/products/butterfly-eco-weave), which may or may not be what you were referring to a year ago. Either way, questions need a permanent [mcve], and external links are not a good substitute, as they break easily ([see here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)).